# How do I get a property into a sping-webflow flow xml

Tags: cas, spring-webflow

I have a standard Spring MVC with WebFlow.  (CAS 4.2.1)  In the login-webflow.xml there is a login view-state:

```
<view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="loginView" model="credential">
```

I have a property in my properties file:

```
loginPage=myNewPage
```

And I want to replace the "view" value with the property like this:

```
<view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="${loginPage}" model="credential">
```

This of course is not working.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> This of course is not working. Any Ideas?

Yes. Dont think it can be done using `login-webflow.xml`.

What you need to do instead is:

- Remove the view-state from the XML flow definition
- Programmatically construct the view-state and add it to the login flow definition on startup.
- ...read the property and build the view appropriately.

Doing so requires that you use the Spring Webflow Java APIs, and you can take inspiration from future CAS versions such as 5+ that autoconfigure the webflow dynamically at runtime removing XML altogether using the same strategy.

Doing so seems like a pretty non-trivial and complicated thing to do in CAS 4.2.1 that was EOLed at least a few years ago. YMMV.